# Skype API C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, api, skype

Разбираю API Скайпа. Пытаюсь научиться программно звонить. 
Код:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SKYPE4COMLib;
using System.Threading;

namespace SkypeAPI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private static Skype _skype = new Skype();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_skype.Client.IsRunning)
            {
                _skype.Client.Start(false, true);
            }
            _skype.Attach();
        }

        private static void sendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            _skype.SendMessage(user, message);
        }

        private static void spam()
        {
            foreach (User user in _skype.Friends)
                sendMessage(user.Handle, "");
        }

        private static void calling()
        {
            Call call = _skype.PlaceCall("+380*********"); //мой моб
        }

        private static void christmass(object obj)
        {
            int speed = Convert.ToInt32(obj);
            TUserStatus[] arr = { TUserStatus.cusOnline, TUserStatus.cusAway, TUserStatus.cusDoNotDisturb };
            while(true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                    _skype.ChangeUserStatus(arr[i]);
                Thread.Sleep(speed);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread th = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(christmass));
            th.Start(200);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calling();
        }
    }
}
```

Не работает метод `calling()`. Хотя сначала в самый первый раз при компиляции с таким кодом заработал. Деньги на счету хоть и немного, но имеются (0.71$). Из самого скайпа звонок идет.
Что делаю не так?

Comment: А этот API разве не прикрыли?

Comment: @PavelMayorov не знаю, но другие методы работают

Answer (score 1):

Майкрософт сильно урезали SkypeApi, по этому, если вы хотите сделать более менее серьезное, вам потребуется найти старую рабочую версию скайпа, подойдет к примеру версия 6.18.

[Тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/238363/) статья, в которой более подробно описан данный вопрос.